# How do I pull specific data from a SQLITE3 database with userinput

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

So right now I am trying to ask for user input such as "what password do you need from the SQLITE3 database and then trying to pull the data from the database. I know how to get specific data from an SQLITE3 database by doing

```
user_input = input("What website would you like the password to>")
c.execute("SELECT FROM passwords WHERE website="whatever website"}")
```

How do I put the user_input value into the c.execute?

Comment: you should avoid putting user input directly in your sql otherwise you expose your self to sql injection attacks, instead you should use place holders in your sql and pass in the variable as a bind paramater like `c.execute('SELECT FROM passwords WHERE website=?', (user_input,))`

Comment: you can read more about execute and parameters here.....https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped